# Is $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2+1}+\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2 +1}+...$ analytic for $|z|>2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, fractals, complex-dynamics

Let $z$ be a complex number. Let |.| denote be the absolute value. Let $n$ be a positive integer.
Let $f_1(z)=z^2+1$. Let $f_n(z)=f_1(f_{n-1}(z)).$

Is $g(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}+\dfrac{1}{f_1(z)}+\dfrac{1}{f_2(z)}+$  $...$ analytic for $|z|>2$ ?

Comment: Additional question : Is it possible to perform analytic continuation such that $g$ is meromorphic on the entire complex plane with a single pole at $z=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is analytic on $|z|>2$ if the denominators of every term are nonzero for $|z|>2$. So we want to determine if there exists a solution for $f_n(z)=0$ when $|z|>2$ for any $n$.

Now, it's obvious that both $z$ and $z^2+1$ have zeros only within $|z|<2$. Let's look at the rest of the sequence.

If $f_n(z)=0$, then we know that $f_{n-1}(z)$ must be a zero of $z^2+1$ - that is, $f_{n-1}(z)=\pm i$. And it iterates - for some $h$ that is a root of $f_{m}(h)=0$, $f_{n-m}(z)=h$ when $f_n(z)=0$.

And so, the easiest way to look at this is "if $|h|\leq 2$, can $|z|>2$?"

Suppose that $|h|\leq 2$ and is a solution to $f_{n-1}(z)=0$. Then we have that

$$
f_1(z)=z^2+1=h=h_x+ih_y
$$
where $h_x^2+h_y^2\leq 4$. And so we have

$$\begin{align}
z &= \pm\sqrt{(h_x-1)+ih_y}\\
& = \pm\sqrt{\sqrt{(h_x-1)^2+h_y^2}e^{i\tan^{-1}\left(h_y/(h_x-1)\right)}}\\
 &= \pm \sqrt[4]{(h_x-z)^2+h_y^2}e^{i\tan^{-1}\left(h_y/(h_x-1)\right)/2}
\end{align}$$
And so,

$$\begin{align}
|z| &= \sqrt[4]{(h_x-1)^2+h_y^2}&\\
& = \sqrt[4]{h_x^2+h_y^2-2h_x+1}&\\
&\leq \sqrt[4]{4-2h_x+1} &\textrm{ as } &h_x^2+h_y^2\leq 4\\
&\leq \sqrt[4]{9} &\textrm{ as } &-2\leq h_x\leq2\\
&= \sqrt{3}\\
&<2
\end{align}$$
Therefore, $|z|<2$ if $|h|\leq 2$, and there cannot be any solution to $f_n(z)=0$ on $|z|>2$ for any $n$. Therefore, the function is analytic.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
g(1/z)=z+\frac{z^2}{1+z^2}+\frac{z^4}{(1+z^2)^2+z^4}+\dots
$$
where each successive term is the reciprocal of ($1$ plus the square of the reciprocal of the previous term). The numerator of each term is $z^{2^k}$ and the denominator is a degree $2^k$ polynomial with constant coefficient $1$.

**Hint:** Note that if $|z|\gt2$ then $|z^2+1|\gt\frac32|z|$